# UnicodeDecodeError error when displaying dataframe on ipython notebook

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

I run 
Windows 7 64-bit

Python 2.7.9 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit)| [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

Pandas version 0.15.2

Jypiter notebook
IPython version 3.0.0.

Here is the problem I am facing:

When I run

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [u'α']})
df
```

where α is the greek 'a' character, I get the error

> ---
>
> UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         2 test_df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [u'α']})
>         3 # test_df = pd.DataFrame([u'Hello \u2013 World'])
>   ----> 4 test_df
>
> C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\displayhook.pyc in
>   **call**(self, result)
>       236                 self.write_format_data(format_dict, md_dict)
>       237                 self.log_output(format_dict)
>   --> 238             self.finish_displayhook()
>       239 
>       240     def cull_cache(self):
>
> C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\zmq\displayhook.pyc in
>   finish_displayhook(self)
>        70         sys.stderr.flush()
>        71         if self.msg['content']['data']:
>   ---> 72             self.session.send(self.pub_socket, self.msg, ident=self.topic)
>        73         self.msg = None
>        74
>
> C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\zmq\session.pyc in
>   send(self, stream, msg_or_type, content, parent, ident, buffers,
>   track, header, metadata)
>       647         if self.adapt_version:
>       648             msg = adapt(msg, self.adapt_version)
>   --> 649         to_send = self.serialize(msg, ident)
>       650         to_send.extend(buffers)
>       651         longest = max([ len(s) for s in to_send ])
>
> C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\zmq\session.pyc in
>   serialize(self, msg, ident)
>       551             content = self.none
>       552         elif isinstance(content, dict):
>   --> 553             content = self.pack(content)
>       554         elif isinstance(content, bytes):
>       555             # content is already packed, as in a relayed message
>
> C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\zmq\session.pyc in
>   (obj)
>        83 # disallow nan, because it's not actually valid JSON
>        84 json_packer = lambda obj: jsonapi.dumps(obj, default=date_default,
>   ---> 85     ensure_ascii=False, allow_nan=False,
>        86 )
>        87 json_unpacker = lambda s: jsonapi.loads(s)
>
> C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\jsonapi.pyc in dumps(o,
>   **kwargs)
>        38         kwargs['separators'] = (',', ':')
>        39 
>   ---> 40     s = jsonmod.dumps(o, **kwargs)
>        41 
>        42     if isinstance(s, unicode):
>
> C:\Anaconda\lib\json__init__.pyc in dumps(obj, skipkeys,
>   ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators,
>   encoding, default, sort_keys, **kw)
>       248         check_circular=check_circular, allow_nan=allow_nan, indent=indent,
>       249         separators=separators, encoding=encoding, default=default,
>   --> 250         sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
>       251 
>       252
>
> C:\Anaconda\lib\json\encoder.pyc in encode(self, o)
>       208         if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
>       209             chunks = list(chunks)
>   --> 210         return ''.join(chunks)
>       211 
>       212     def iterencode(self, o, _one_shot=False):
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position
>   12: ordinal not in range(128)

but I do not get error when I run just `df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [u'α']})`

After searching for some hours in the web I found that some suggest

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

as a solution while others suggest that it should never be used. This code displays the data frame indeed, but it breaks `print`
Other suggestions were to upgrade to Python3.

What I would like to ask is if there is a solution to displaying the dataframe apart from upgrading to Python 3 and a code that breaks `print`.

Comment: This works just fine for me in Python 3 and in Python 2.7.9, using Pandas v0.18.  Try upgrading the Pandas module, if you don't want to go to Python 3.  Also your IPython is out of date too, though it doesn't seem relevant to this problem.

Comment: I uninstalled anaconda and installed again. Now with
Python Version: 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Pandas Version: 0.18.1
IPython Version: 4.2.0

runs as desired.

Thanks!

Comment: No problem.  Unicode can be a pain in Python 2.x, so some day when you upgrade to 3.x it will be handled a lot more smoothly.